# Try to open file using Click Counter with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to prevent user from predicting the target script (test.php) AND do the whole "counter" logic on the server side.
I don't know how to achieve it with PHP.
I would like to open the file from the server side with PHP so the client will not have the possibility to see and know what file will open after 15 clicks. Because by typing the URL of the file it is possible to open it even before 15 clicks.
Thanks

HTML

```
<div id='overlay' class='overlay'></div>
<div class="view" id="view"></div>
      
<div class="canvas">
        <div id="totalCounter" class="total-counter"></div>
    
        <button id="clap" class="clap-container" tabindex="-1"></button>
    
        <div id="clicker" class="click-counter">
          <span class="counter"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let accCounter = 0;
let totalCount = 0;

document.getElementById('totalCounter').innerText = totalCount;

document.getElementById('clap').onclick = function() {
    const clap = document.getElementById('clap');
    const clickCounter = document.getElementById("clicker");
    upClickCounter();
    loadDoc();
}

function upClickCounter() {
    const clickCounter = document.getElementById("clicker");
    const totalClickCounter = document.getElementById('totalCounter');

    accCounter ++;
    clickCounter.children[0].innerText = '+' + accCounter;
    totalClickCounter.innerText = totalCount + accCounter;
}

 function loadDoc() {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
     };
     xhttp.open("GET", "clickcheck.php", true);
     xhttp.send();
    
     document.getElementById("view").style.visibility="visible";
     if (totalCount + accCounter%15) {
     document.getElementById('view').style.visibility="hidden";
     }
     document.getElementById('overlay').style.display  = 'block';
     if (totalCount + accCounter%15) {
         document.getElementById('overlay').style.display  = 'none';
     }
    }
```

clickcheck.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!array_key_exists('clickcount', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['clickcount'] = 1;
}
if ($_SESSION['clickcount'] < 15) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
    exit();
} else {
    include("test.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not simply include the same check you have in `clickcheck.php` on `test.php` (in order to protect whatever you deliver on `test.php`)?

Comment: I think there is problem in the clickcheck.php script it seems not to work correctly for some reason

Comment: Only you know your requirements but, if i understand correctly, you're not incrementing your counter.